# Calculating a FileName Pattern dynamically for "Path" in Azure Function (Blob Trigger)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I've Just created a Azure Blob Trigger in Azure Function.I can configure that the Blob Name which trigger the Function under the "Path" Properties. I see some examples of how to set the name of the blob [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#pattern)

But in my Case i want to trigger my Azure Function.When ever a file in the pattern like

**ABL_{TIMESTAMP}.XML**

e.g,

ABL_07022017_000114.xml

when i Changed my path as

**"path" :"ABL_{filename}.xml"** it works but not for the timestamp i'm afraid

Is there any other way like Using Regex Pattern to find the filenamepattern dynamically for the "Path"

Thanks in Advance 
Jayendran

Comment: Do you mean you only want to match files with valid timestamp and skip files like "ABL_bla.xml"?

Comment: Exactly, I do want to trigger only those matching files.dont want the rest

Comment: I don't think you can do it directly in the binding... Any problem to filter it out inside the function code?

Comment: I've just new to this one.So just i've asked about the way i knew it. If this can be done outside of the function It also be helpful for me. But as i mentioned earlier if we filter it outside of the function,does the trigger will filter all the matching files "ABL_bla.xml" ? or the one with the correct Time stamp "ABL_07022017_000114.xml"?

Comment: My suggestion was to accept all the files (including ABL_bla) and then check the correctness of the filename inside the function.

Comment: In that case the blob trigger will trigger all the bla bla files , then I have to filter those with my pattern (regex) inside my code? No direct binding

Comment: Yes, binding filters "ABL_{name}.xml" and you validate "name" yourself. I guess you need to parse it into timestamp anyway.

Comment: Ok I will try that.In the meantime if you provide any suggestions/answers to my questions you are welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no direct binding method to directly filter the FilePattern. So i'm just filtering within my code. It just working fine